# Google maps street view does not work with angular 6 when I call it multiples times

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have included a functionality to open a google street view in a location. It is showing when I click in a button and is hiding when I click it again. This is in a modal bootstrap popup.

It is working fine the first time I click on the button to show it. But when I close the modal popup and I open it again (or in any other locations popup), it is showing the street view wrong. With a big zoom and without the bottons of the map to zoom and move around.

FIRST TIME I OPEN THE STREET VIEW:
[image]

AFTER CLOSE IT AND OPEN THE SAME OR ANOTHER LOCATION IN THE STREET VIEW:
[image]

My html code is:

```
[...]
<button type="button" class="btn btn-simple-dark" (click)="initialize()" [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapse">
                {{ isCollapsed  ? 'Mostrar' : 'Ocultar' }} Street View
            </button>
            <div [ngClass]="{streetView: !isCollapsed}" id="street-view"></div>
[...]
```

And my .ts file is:

```
[... The imports...]
export class ModalMupiComponent extends ModalComponent {

  isCollapsed = true;
  flag = false;
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
    super(activeModal);
  }
  initialize() {
    if (this.flag) {
      this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
    } else {
        const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
        document.getElementById('street-view'),
        {
          position: {lat: this.obj.lat, lng: this.obj.lon},
          pov: {heading: 165, pitch: 0},
          zoom: 1,
        });
        this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
        this.flag = true;
    }
      }

}
```

Can someone help me?

Regards.

Comment: Hey, could it be that you are not setting your this.flag variable false again ?

Comment: No, the flag variable is only use to prevent the reload of the street view component several times if you click the show/hide button multiple times. In any case, I have tried to remove that if statement with flag variable and it didn't work